# Java Sending Email to Shared Mailbox thru SMTP Server

Tags: email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am new to Java Mail API. I am trying to send emails thru SMTP server. We have to send email to multiple addresses, out of which few are shared mailboxes. When I execute the send email code, emails are delivered to emails ids which are user email ids but not shared mailboxes. Logs show the email is sent from smtp server to shared mailbox address but the emails are not delivered.

Can we send email to Shared mailbox thru SMTP server?

Using Javax.mail 1.4 version

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

Let me know if I am missing any configuration for sending email to shared mailbox.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is on the server, not the client.  What kind of server are you using?  What kind of address are you using for a shared mailbox?  Also, you might want to use a [newer version of JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

Comment: I dont have server details other than host and port. I did not install the server as created by different team and used for different projects. Address of the shared mailbox we are using is mailbox_name@domainname.com

Comment: You need to talk to the team that installed or manages the server to look at log files to find out why the mail isn't being delivered.

Comment: Server team could not resolve the issue. So they changes the shared mailbox to user account mailbox which is working fine.